# Why does SortedDictionary not implement IReadOnlyDictionary?

Tags: design, .net, collections

The .NET type `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not implement the interface `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, although `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does.

It is trivial to make `SortedDictionary` implement `IReadOnlyDictionary` by subclassing it (< 10 LOCs).

But I guess there are good reasons why the framework developers did not do it and that’s why I shouldn’t do it. What are those reasons?

Comment: Just a guess, though maybe SortedDictionary optimizes sorting by sorting only upon retrieving data, so you can insert many values without sorting each time.  However in doing so, *reading* a value is actually changing the dictionary's state, hence it isn't read only.  This is just my idea, so I won't post it as a solution.

Comment: I guess they simply forgot to add it, or considered it too much work for too little gain.

Comment: @Neil: Good idea! However, they are using red-black trees, and the code does not seem to modify the collection. Moreover, [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says about thread safety: “A SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified.” So I think that’s not the reason.

Comment: @Martin It's reasonable to assume there is some detail *like* that going on though.  Otherwise I can't see why they wouldn't make `SortedDictionary` implement `IReadOnlyDictionary`.

Comment: Hmmm. Also looks like SortedList doesn't support IReadOnlyList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at MSDN today, one can see that the [MSDN documentation page for `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` *does* implement `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

According to the internet archive, that was not the case on [November 14th, 2013](http://web.archive.org/web/20131114230244/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Given that information, it is likely that it was simply an oversight from Microsoft, fixed in a recent .NET point update.

Comment: Indeed. The MSDN page mentions “.NET 4.5.3”, and today, sourceof.net shows 4.5.2, where IReadOnlyDictionary is not implemented.